# python matrix does not hold its values

Tags: python, matrix, return-value

I started a dicussion in another page (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767260/matricial-operation-in-python) about matrix operation problems. First, I though that the problem could be related to the opertaions byselves, but now I changed my mind. I think that I found where the problem lies. Please, take a look in the following code (the pyepidsis library I made by myself)

```
import pyepidsis as pesis
import networkx as nx

###### PARAMETROS DE ENTRADA #########

ns = 5 #numero inicial de agentes susceptiveis (0)
ni = 2 #numero inicial de agentes infectados (1)
b = 0.01 #probabilidade de um agente susceptivel se tornar infectado
g = 0 #probabilidade de um agente infectado se tornar susceptivel
top = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(ns+ni,1) #topologia utilizada na dinamica
it = 10 #numero de iteracoes
rep = 2 #numero de repeticoes

######## SIMULACAO NUMERICA ##########

E = pesis.distribuicao_aleatoria(ns,ni)
T = nx.adjacency_matrix(top) #matriz de adjacencia da topologia

suscep = [] #lista que guarda o numero de cada agente de cada
infec = []  #iteracao e cada repeticao
suscep_medio = [] #lista que guarda o valor medio de 
infec_medio = []  #cada agente a cada iteracao

for i in range(rep):
  print E
  qtde_suscep = pesis.dinamica(ni,ns,E,T,it,b,g)
  suscep.append(qtde_suscep)
```

When I run this script, the values of the matrix `E` changes in every i-loop. I want to fix it, so keeping E constant. Can someone find the problem here?

I have been trying to debug this problem for a week. I really don't know what to do. The following code shows what `pesis.dinamica`does

```
def dinamica(ni,ns,E_aux,T,it,b,g):
  qtde_suscep = [] #listas que guardarao o numero de cada
  qtde_infec = []  #tipo de agente a cada iteracao
  qtde_suscep.append(ns) #numero de susceptiveis e 
  qtde_infec.append(ni)  #infectados no inicio da dinamica
  contador = range(ni+ns)

  for j in range(1,it):
    B = matriz_si(ni+ns,b)
    G = matriz_is(ni+ns,g)
    np.random.shuffle(contador)

    for k in contador:
      E_aux[k,0] = interacao(k,E_aux,B[k,:],G[k,0],T[k,:])

    contador_suscep=np.where(E_aux==0)[0]     #conta quantos
    contador_suscep=np.array(contador_suscep) #susceptiveis ha
    contador_suscep=len(contador_suscep[0])   #na populacao e
    qtde_suscep.append(contador_suscep)       #guarda essa
    qtde_infec.append((ni+ns) - qtde_suscep[-1])    #informacao

  return qtde_suscep
```

Comment: Hard to tell with this piece of code. What (type) is E? What happens inside `pesis.dinamica`? You have to debug a litle further for yourself, e.g. add some prints inside `pesis.dinamica`. And read something about pythons call-by mechanism, e.g. [here](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm) or [here](http://learntofish.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/call-by-object-reference-call-by-sharing/)

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying `E`

```
E_aux[k,0] = interacao(k,E_aux,B[k,:],G[k,0],T[k,:])
```

If E is a numpy array (or other kind of mutable object), it will be passed as reference, and all modifications will pass on. The solution? Stuff this at the beginning of the function (only one of them):

```
E_aux = E_aux.copy()  # Assuming Numpy array or
E_aux = copy.copy(E_aux) # Assuming it is something else, using stdlib copy
```

You are creating a fresh new copy of the data. It will be in the local scope and die when you exit the function. The original `E_aux` will remain untouched.

The reason for Python's behaviour is that if you had a very big array (say, 4 GB) and you copied every time you pass it on to a function, your memory usage will double, and you would have to wait for all the data to be copied.